# Can someone explain how a While Loop using the Dir function works in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm fairly new to VBA and needed to make a script for work. The script would look in a directory and import any .txt files found into a new worksheet in the workbook. I.e. if there were 20 .txt files, I would end up with 20 worksheets. I found some code online that does this perfectly, exactly as I want it to. The problem is, I don't really understand how it works. I've never used the Dir function, and it appears the loop focuses on this, but I'm still confused as to how this is looping from one file to the next. If someone could help me understand, or add comments to the code, that would be really helpful. Thanks.

Code is:

```
    Sub LoadFiles()
Dim idx As Integer
Dim fpath As String
Dim fname As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
idx = 0
fpath = "C:\MyFolderLocation"
fname = Dir(fpath)
While (Len(fname) > 0)
    idx = idx + 1
    Sheets.Add.Name = fname
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" _
      & fpath & fname, Destination:=Range("A1"))
        .Name = "a" & idx
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 437
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileOtherDelimiter = ","
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        fname = Dir
    End With
Wend
```

End Sub

Comment: how about just reading up on the topic straight from the sources mouth [MSDN Dir](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk008ty4(v=vs.90).aspx). Then supplement that with plenty of other articles written on the topic! ... I also VTC because this off-topic for reason of looking for a tutorial. Lastly, welcome to SO. Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to receive better help in the future. :)

Comment: I'd start by looking at the DIR function, looks like you're picking up files, then when the file is nothing, i.e len=0 stop.  While = while this is true do this.

Comment: It won't help you if you don't know C -- but is some ways `Dir` in VBA has always reminded me a bit of `strtok()` in C -- they are used in loops in roughly similar ways.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Dir function returns, one at the time, filenames from a directory.

When you call Dir() with a path to a directory as an argument, it will return to you the first filename from that directory.

When you call Dir() without an argument, it will return to you the next filename from the directory until there are no more files, in which case a null name is returned.

So in order to process all the files in directory you need Dir(path) once, followed by Dir() as long as that returns a name.

How do you test if a name is returned?
`fname>""`
is a way, here they use
`len(fname)>0`
where len is another function that takes a string as argument and returns the length of that string.

So comes the "as long as there are files" part. That is implemented with a loop structure

```
while *condition*  
    ... do things  
end while
```

in this case

```
While (Len(fname) > 0)
    '...
    fname=Dir
Wend
```

Comment: Thank you, this makes a lot of sense. The function call with and without a parameter was tripping me up.